# Capturing Preview Frame in Portrait

Tags: android, android-camera

Is there any way to acquire the preview frame directly in portrait inside onPreviewFrame method?
I've tried:

```
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

but this seems to work only for the display. The doc reports:

> Set the clockwise rotation of preview display in degrees. This affects
>   the preview frames and the picture displayed after snapshot. This
>   method is **useful for portrait mode applications**.
>
> **This does not affect the order of byte array passed in onPreviewFrame**(byte[], Camera), JPEG pictures, or recorded videos.
>   This method is not allowed to be called during preview.

I'm targetting API level >= 8, and I've a portrait locked app. I want to avoid manually rotating byte array of data passed as frame.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Try this it will work

```
public void takeSnapPhoto() {
camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        int format = parameters.getPreviewFormat();
        //YUV formats require more conversion
        if (format == ImageFormat.NV21 || format == ImageFormat.YUY2 || format == ImageFormat.NV16) {
            int w = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
            int h = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;
            // Get the YuV image
            YuvImage yuv_image = new YuvImage(data, format, w, h, null);
            // Convert YuV to Jpeg
            Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, w, h);
            ByteArrayOutputStream output_stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            yuv_image.compressToJpeg(rect, 100, output_stream);
            byte[] byt = output_stream.toByteArray();
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                // Write to SD Card
                File file = createFileInSDCard(FOLDER_PATH, "Image_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
                //Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(file);
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                outStream.write(byt);
                outStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
        }
    }
});}
```

Comment: This code only converts preview data to image file. Does not answer the question.